# Can't boot into Ubuntu 18.04 nor Windows from GRUB bootloader

Tags: ubuntu, boot, windows

I had a dual boot setup for around a month now that was working fine. Today I was using Windows and got a blue screen of death.

When I tried booting back up, I got a registry error (REGISTRY ERROR). I then tried booting into my Ubuntu 18.04 and got another error:

> error: failure writing sector 0x (memory address) to 'hd1'.

Most solutions involve using one system to repair the other but I cannot boot into either system. The GRUB menu works and functions as it would normally.

This issue came on suddenly, and I don't have any idea what caused this issue.

Answer (score 0):

A hardware fault such as a drive failure can cause both failures.

Try making a LiveUSB on another PC to test with: Get the [ISO file for Ubuntu 19.10](https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you/?version=19.10&architecture=amd64)  and [check it for download errors](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu).

Make the LiveUSB with persistence following Ubuntu's instructions on [Windows](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows), [MacOS](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos), or [Ubuntu](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu).

Once you make the LiveUSB, boot from it, and test your internal drive thoroughly.